# Adding minitests/reporters to test_helper.rb - error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So this is a bit beyond my knowledge. I added the minitests/reporters to test_helper.rb by doing the following :

I installed minitest reporters gem : `gem install minitest-reporters`
and added the `require` in the `test_helper.rb`:

```
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.
```

When I run tests, here is what I get : Should I reinstall all gems?

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 15917
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rails db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': cannot load such file -- minitest/reporters (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/test_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:11:in `block in require_files'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in `require_files'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:76:in `plugin_rails_init'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib/minitest.rb:80:in `block in init_plugins'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib/minitest.rb:78:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib/minitest.rb:78:in `init_plugins'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib/minitest.rb:129:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/test.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:95:in `test'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<m
```

Comment: Do you bother to read the error message?  `Run rails db:migrate to create it, then try again.` Also do you add the reporters gem to the Gemfile.?

Comment: I did gem install minitest-reporters but I don't see minitest in gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and it worked :

1- Added to test_helper.rb the following :
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

2- Added to Gemfile the following :
gem 'minitest', group: :test
gem 'minitest-reporters', group: :test

3- Run rails test